# Marginal distribtuion with noninformative prior

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, uninformative-prior

For $i=1, \ldots, K$ and $j=1, \ldots,n$, assume the following model.
\begin{align}
X_{ij} \mid \mu_i & \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2) \nonumber \\
P(\mu_i, \sigma^2) & \propto 1/\sigma^2
\end{align}
We assume everything is independent. Then the posterior is as below
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\mu-\bar X_i}{s/ \sqrt{n}} \sim T_{n-1}
\end{align*}
With this noninformative prior, is it possible to derive the marginal distribution of $\bar X_i$?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that no, with improper prior distributions, the marginal distribution of the data will not be proper.